# PHP - explode and get lsat part in single command

Tags: php

It is not possible in php to do either of the following:

```
end(explode(',', $theString));
explode(',', $theString)[0];  // 5.4 i think you can?
```

but is there another way to do this?

I completely understand that its only 1 extra line of code to get the value but it becomes a little messy if there are a few cases of this in a certain place in the code.

Comment: The second will work in 5.4. The one line alternative is to do `list($first, $second) = explode(',', $theString);` . See [`list()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: Your first line also works here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xcs-h18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list($target) = explode(",",$theString);
```

You can even apply this to arbitrary indices, not just the first:

```
list(,$second) = explode(",",$theString);
list($first,,$third) = explode(",",$theString);
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Pre PHP 5.4 to get this in one line:

```
<?php

list($f) = explode(',', $s);

// if you want to confuse people
($a = explode(',', $s)) && ($f = $a[0]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `strrpos` and `substr`?

```
$value = substr($theString, strrpos($theString, ',')+1);
```